# How to check and create databases in CouchDB with Node.JS?

Tags: node.js, couchdb

I'm trying to create a small web application and I have an issue. In my code, I initialize my database name in the beginning and before my application executes and I'd like to check if the database name exists on the server and if not create a database with that name. So in other words, I'm trying to do something like this;

```
if(dbName is not exists){
couch.createDatabase(dbName).then(function(){
     console.log('Database created');
 };
}
```

But I'm not sure how to do this properly. I'm trying to learn and use npm node-couchdb package and I'd be grateful if you can help me to solve this issue without using any other package.

Update: Now I can check if the database exist with couch.listDatabases() and if not create a new one with couch.createDatabase with following;

```
couch.listDatabases().then(function(dbs){
var controller = 0;
console.log(dbs);
for(var i= 0; i <= dbs.length; i++){
    if(dbName == dbs[i]){
        controller += 1;
    }
}
if(controller == 0){
    couch.createDatabase(dbName).then(function(){
     console.log('Database created');
 },
 function(err){
     res.send(err);
 });
}
});
```

I can see the new database on the server, but when I try to reach it with my application I get this error;

```
{"code":"EDOCMISSING","body":{"error":"not_found","reason":"missing"}}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can get the list of the databases like this:

```
couch.listDatabases()
.then(
   dbs => dbs.map(...), 
   err => {
   // request error occured 
});
```

and check if your db already exist or not.

Comment: I was just working on this. Now I can check the db is exist or not. And if it's not exist, then I create a db as well, but when I try to reach that database, I get the following error; {"code":"EDOCMISSING","body":{"error":"not_found","reason":"missing"}} do you have any idea why?

Comment: Here's the jsfiddle thanks for the help, https://jsfiddle.net/9fg9mtmv/

Comment: i guess the error occurs inside couch.get(dbName, viewUrl). Are you sure that the db gets created?

Comment: Yes, I can see it in Futon.

Comment: Pretty hard to say... I suggest trying one of these 2 other modules wich are very well document and see if somehing changes: [nano](https://github.com/dscape/nano) or [cradle](https://github.com/flatiron/cradle).